# How can I return my object property name as node name

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

I am stuck while returning api result, I have a class like

```
public partial class Sample
{
    [JsonProperty("classificator")]
    public List<Classificator> Classificator { get; set; }
}

public partial class Classificator
{
    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say **GetJson** method retrieve our data from the database, there are 2 records and the data like

-- Value - Description

1- A     - AXA

2- B     - BXA

```
response = GetJson(); // this method gets data from db 
return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```

when I return this, it's like

```
{
    "classificator": [{
            "Value": "A",
            "Description": "AXA"
        }, {
            "Value": "B",
            "Description": "BXA"
        }
    ]
}
```

but I would like to see like, I want to see bellowing result;

```
{
    "classificator": [{
            "A": "AXA"
        }, {
            "B" : "BXA"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to ask you maybe someone knows a good practice or document(tutorial) about it.

I solve it by using,  *Dictionary < string, model >*

but I need to return a huge nested field I cant implement this solution for all different nodes.

Comment: maybe a custom converter https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm or https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm?

Comment: let me know when you find an answer ayvaras :-)

Comment: @EgeTuncoz sure.

Comment: What is this huge nested field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using **Dictionary< string, object >**

I put 2 nested objects inside of an object value. In my case it looked some complex I refactor and try to work through readable dictionary hierarchy.

basically for this example it something like below,

```
Dictionary<string, object> fooDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

fooDict.Add("A", "AXA"); // in my case I put 2 nested object to value field
fooDict.Add("B", "BXA"); 

var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fooDict);

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\xxx\result.txt", true))
{
    file.WriteLine(serializedObject);
}
```